# why would openat() use file descriptor decremented by 1

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am tracing `open()` and `openat()` Linux system calls using a library that I load with `LD_PRELOAD=...`.  I have a process that descends down a directory path.  It does `open()` on a directory, which returns file descriptor 8, then it proceeds to correctly open the child directory by `openat()`, using relative path from the parent directory, but using file descriptor 7 (??!) for the parent.

Why would that be so??